# SharePoint 2010 Infopath problems in Edge

Tags: 2010, infopath

On one of our SharePoint 2010 websites we display InfoPath Forms through the InfoPath Form Web Part. This works great in most browsers, but we recently found out the forms are not loading in Edge (they do load in browsers like **IE9/IE11/Chrome/Firefox**).

We did some google work, but any real answers still remain to be found. 
We tried `content="IE=Edge"` but that didn't do much.

Is there anything else we can do to make InfoPath Forms work in Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turned out infopath forms load just fine in Edge and the problem was in a javascript file. The js file did some actions before it fired `_InfoPath.OnLoad()` if the browser was not Chrome (as that browser can't handle that command), but Edge gave a false positive on the check for Chrome and thus didn't call the load command. The result was no loading of infopath form as Edge does need the `_InfoPath.OnLoad()` command.